# How to query for revisions in a TFS 2012 database?

Tags: mysql, tfs

I'm writing a query that pulls all work items with a certain state from a specific day, but the state of those work items might have changed since then.

I know work items have a Revisions property which holds a list of previous renditions of the work item that would be great to query against. TFS has a State Change Date query built in which I figured I could also use.

I'd like to go straight for the query so I don't have to pull all of the work items that existed on the date, looping through each one's revisions, and keeping the ones with a state that I'm interested in. I figure there has to be a better way than that.

Question is similar to https://superuser.com/questions/735431/query-tfs-for-items-that-changed-to-a-certain-status, however, I want this query to work for more than just a resolved state.

Comment: Why  not use the WIQL? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb130306.aspx

Comment: I didn't see it had an ASOF clause. If it works how I'm understanding it to, that'd be perfect! I'll give it a try, thanks!